# Emoji with beamer overlay specifications

Tags: beamer, emoji

This is an example that uses the emoji package along with an overlay specification to show each line individually. Is it possible to make the emoji fully transparent, as with the rest of the text?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{emoji}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item This will appear on the first slide.
\item This will appear on the second slide. \emoji{drop-of-blood}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Current result:

[image: first slide]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "fully transparent" is all you want and not a non-zero transparency level, you can remove the line `\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}`.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{emoji}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item This will appear on the first slide.
\item This will appear on the second slide. \emoji{drop-of-blood}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: I did not expect that!

Comment: Totally didn't expect that either! I had a stray `\setbeamercovered{dynamic}`, and it seems beamer can't make emoji fonts partially opaque?

Answer (score 2):

Not fully automated, but `\only<2->{}` seems to work.

> [image]

---

```
% LuaTeX because of the emoji package.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{emoji}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item This will appear on the first slide.
\item This will appear on the second slide. \only<2->{\emoji{drop-of-blood}}
\item This will appear on the third slide.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]